# How can i resolve [object Object] alert?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, oracle

I have a problem [object Object] when I started project.

I want to access database value and then I want to create new tag.

ShareList.js

```
function ata() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home.Master/ShareList",
        contentType: "application/json;charset-utf-8",
        success: function (result) {

            var MyData = JSON.parse(result.d);
            alert(MyData);
            var i;
            var data = MyData.Table;
            alert(data);
            var maindiv = document.getElementById("fh5co-board");
            var sablon;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var divitem = document.createElement("div");
                divitem.setAttribute("class", "item");
                var divanimate = document.createElement("div");
                divanimate.setAttribute("class", "animate - box");
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.setAttribute("class", "image-popup fh5co-board-img");
                a.setAttribute("href", "#");
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.setAttribute("src",data[i].PATH);

                a.appendChild(img);
                var divText = document.createElement("div");
                divText.setAttribute("class", "fh5co-desc");
                var stringName = data[i].NAME;

                divText.appendChild(stringName);

                divanimate.appendChild(a);
                divanimate.appendChild(divText);
                divitem.appendChild(divanimate);
                maindiv.appendChild(divitem);
            }

        },
        error: function (hata) {

            alert(hata);
        }


    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(ata, 1000);
});
```

Home.Master.cs
I want to access database this page with OracleDataAdapter.

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OracleConnection cnn = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


 public  string ShareList()
    {
        cnn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

        OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT Q.NAME,Q.CREATEDATE,P.PATH FROM QUESTION Q INNER JOIN PHOTO P ON P.PATH=Q.PHOTOID",cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented);
        return data;
    }


}
```

Comment: The `$.ajax()` call is missing the `data:` option to specify the parameters being sent.

Comment: `MyData` is an object, so `alert(MyData)` will display `[object Object]`. Use `alert(JSON.stringify(MyData));` to see the contents, or use `console.log(MyData)`.

Comment: You may also add dataType: "json" to your ajax call.